# Buscar por foreign key DRF

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Tengo dos modelos de Django con una relación de uno a muchos entre Productos y Categorías

**Mi archivo models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='categorys')
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Categoría'
        verbose_name_plural='Categorías'
        ordering=['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products')
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Producto'
        verbose_name_plural='Productos'
        ordering=['-created']

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

**Mi archivo serializers.py**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id','name','image','description','price','category_id')

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id','name','image','description')
```

**Mi archivo views.py**

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

**Mi archivo urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'product-list', ProductViewSet)
router.register(r'category-list', CategoryViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Hasta el momento puedo obtener todos los productos y todas las categorías, **pero lo que necesito ahora es obtener la lista de productos que pertenecen a una categoría**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega a tu router  que recibes el parámetro con id:
**router.py**

```
router.register(r'product_by_category/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', ProductByCategoryViewSet)
```

crea tu vista **ProductByCategoryViewSet** en el **views.py**

```
class ProductByCategoryViewSet(viewsets.ListAPIView):
    """This class defines the    ManufacturingOrder behavior of our rest api."""
    serializer_class =   ProductSerializer
    queryset =  Product.objects.all()
    def get_queryset(self):
        category_id = self.kwargs['category_id']
        return self.queryset.filter(category_id__pk=category_id)
```

Comment: Estoy haciendo lo que me dices, pero sale un error en: return self.queryset.filter(parent_id__pk=category_id)

Comment: error: AttributeError: type object 'ProductByCategoryViewSet' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions

Comment: deje un error,  ya lo acomodo, ya edite verifica

Comment: Me sirvió mucho tu ayuda... Gracias

Comment: Aunque la respuesta final la dejé así: **views.py** 'class ProductByCategoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class =   ProductSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        category_id = self.kwargs['id']
        return Product.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)' **urls.py** 'router.register(r'product_by_category/<int:id>', ProductByCategoryViewSet)'