# ¿Cómo puedo traer un campo de otra tabla relacionada a mi queryset de Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Estoy trabajando con django y tengo el modelo relacional de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer un queryset que me traiga los datos de la tabla **PedidosProductos** junto con el **precio** que está en la tabla **Productos**. Esta es la query que tengo:

```
query = PedidosProductos.objects.all()
```

Pero necesito un campo más (**precio**), que esta en la tabla **Productos**

Analogía en SQL:

```
SELECT PP.pedidos_id,
       PP.productos_id,
       PP.cantidad, 
       Prod.precio 
FROM PedidosProductos as PP,
Productos as Prod
WHERE PP.pedidos_id = Prod.id;
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Cómo has definido tus modelos?

Comment: revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/227760/28035) puede que te sirva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero decirte que creo que está mal la sentencia SQL, o no estoy entendiendo la funcionalidad que buscas. Porque estás relacionando `pedido_id`=`producto_id`.

Posiblemente puedas usar [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related),  que te devuelve un QuerySet que "seguirá" las relaciones de clave externa, seleccionando datos adicionales de objetos relacionados cuando ejecuta su consulta.

```
query = PedidosProductos.objects.select_related()
```

Comment: Hola, agradezco la colaboración y las correcciones.